# Using prefetch_related on GenericForeignKeys in the reverse direction

Tags: sql, django

I have Animals and Cages.

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models

class Cage(models.Model):
    ...

class Animal(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    ...
```

First there's the model Cage. I'm currently trying to optimize the number of queries made when iterating through a list of Cages.

Then we have the model Animal. Animals contain a GenericForeignKey. One of the many objects that an Animal points to can be a Cage, but it can also be other objects too, like say Food.

If I wanted to get all of the Animal objects that were in Cage 16, that would be easy. The statement would be something like this:

```
Animal.objects.filter(content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Cage), object_id=16)
```

I could therefore get the animals in each cage with something like:

```
cage_content_type_id = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Cage).id
animals_in_cage = {}
for cage in cages:
    animals_in_cage[cage.id] = Animal.objects.filter(
        content_type_id=cage_content_type_id,
        object_id=cage.id
    )
```

The problem with this code is that it will make `O(n)` SQL queries where `n = len(cages)`. Ideally, I would be able to use something like `prefetch_related` to do a join on the Animal and Cages table ahead of time. However, I cannot figure out any way to do this with GenericForeignKeys moving in the reverse direction. Essentially what I would like to do is this:

```
cages = Cage.objects.prefetch_related('animal').all()
```

but animal is not an attribute of a Cage object and cage is not an attribute of an Animal object in this case. The link between the two is the content type and object id in the Animal model which for some instances represents a cage.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Cage has something like this:

```
animals = GenericRelation(Animal)
```

You can go:

```
Cage.objects.filter(...).prefetch_related('animals').all()
```

(At least in Django 1.8.4.)